# Moving a Gitolite (3) server that is using Git Annex

Tags: gitolite, git-annex

I'm currently in the process of moving a gitolite (3) installation between two
servers. Thankfully, this process is pretty well
[documented](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/install#moving-servers) on the main
project website. However, my repositories makes pretty active use of
[git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) which stores data in various
remotes as well as on the server itself.

Now, I'm not an expert on git-annex, but I know it works a bit differently from
"regular" git, so is there anything one should keep in mind when moving this
kind of installation or does it work just as outlined in the gitolite
documentation above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, I couldn't find any details on how this should
done on a git-annex enabled repository so I decided to simply try it
out. Apparently, the steps as they are written work just fine, even for
git-annex content. That said, be cautious as you're moving stuff. Once the new
server is ready to take over, make sure the old one is disabled, I don't think
the git-annex likes to find 2 identical remotes.

As a minor anecdote: I accidently forgot to `chown`/`chmod` the repositories but
re-running step 6 and onwards without any issues what-so-ever.